# Preciso de Ajuda com erro ao tentar instalar o Composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer

Estou fazendo manutenções e melhorias em um site utilizando o CodeIgniter v2.x e um dos requerimentos do meu cliente, foi fazer o login utilizando Facebook. 
O problema é que preciso instalar o `Composer` e não estou conseguindo. Ano passado eu fiz uma aplicação com Pusher (Chat) e instalei tranquilamente, depois disso eu formatei meu Mac e essa é a primeira vez precisando lidar com o `Composer` desde então.
Voltando ao problema. tem lá o arquivo `composer.json`
E claro, ele requer o `composer.phar` e até ai tudo ok, mas quando clico para instalar/fazer update, ele retorna o seguinte erro

```
    — COMPOSER —
   executing: ./composer.phar install -n -v
   Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Ai não sei se o problema está sendo o meu sistema operacional que é o `MacOS El Capitain`, a versão do Sublime Text, versão do CodeIgniter ou alguma coisa que eu esteja fazendo de muito errada. Alguém tem solução ou sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Instale usando os seguintes passos da página do composer mesmo :

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '070854512ef404f16bac87071a6db9fd9721da1684cd4589b1196c3faf71b9a2682e2311b36a5079825e155ac7ce150d') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

depois mova seu .phar para ser global

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

obs: caso não exista a pasta use:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

execute com o comando:

```
composer
```